# How to fast-blur in css/js?

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery-transit

I am having a performance issue when combining blurred images with some subpixel translate animation (I am using [jQuery Transit](http://ricostacruz.com/jquery.transit/)):

```
filter: blur(5px);^
```

On `mousemove`, blur is recalculated to simulate Depth-of-Field.
When moving, the elements aren't moving as fluid as I would like them to be.

[Demo here](http://www.limesky.net/~steban/index_dev.html)

Buggy movement appears when you click on a bottle in a `-webkit` browser

Any idea/tips how I could accelerate this?

I was thinking about pre-calculating every focus step and using opacity but this is the last solution I would use.

Comment: Switch to `mouseover` you need to blur only when the mouse is over not at every pixel move

Comment: @Ibu this isn't really the issue as event with the keyboard arrows (without mouse-move) the movement is the same, and behaviour is not exactly the same with mouseover as it doesn't blurs progressively but with steps on element hover. but thanks

Comment: this will be be an optimization of your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're translating and scaling the images at the same time, which is causing the jumpiness. Try using translate3d `-webkit-transform: translate3d(x,y,z)` instead and modifying the z position instead of scaling. This should help quite a bit with performance as your animations will now be hardware accelerated.

Comment: I found this hardware trick and added a z value on the css by default to enable hardware acceleration. By the way Transmit doesn't use Z... just discovered this. Ill try to reimplement this with jquery animate